# How to move an element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

**I want to change the position of #superWidget in the DOM.  I want to remove it from #wrapperB and place it in #wrapperA.**

```
<div id="wrapperA">
  <div id="superWidget"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapperB"></div>
```

---

I have tried the following...

```
var copy = $("#superWidget").clone(true, true);
$("#superWidget").remove();
$("#wrapperA").append(copy);
```

...however this breaks a lot of the plugins used by my page.

I do not want to have to rebind everything.  Is there a better way to do this?  (I notice that jquery UI sortable is somehow able to move elements around in the DOM without breaking any interactivity...  there must be a way.)

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Rather than duplicating, just do this:

```
document.getElementById('wrapperA').appendChild(document.getElementById('superWidget'));
```