# Load div content in pop window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to load the div inside the pop up window.

Currently I am able to load the direct html content in it through `document.write` but how do I load a div(with a form in it) inside the pop window.

Here is the current code

```
function myFunction() {
            var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
            myWindow.document.write("<p>Need to load the .content div here</p>");
        }
```

Jquery/JavaScript anything would do.

Here is the working **[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/derixerotu/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: None of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]populate+pop-up+window)?

Comment: replace `<p>` with `<form>` and you have a form. what is the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move an element in the DOM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088650/how-to-move-an-element-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the changes I made to your code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");

    myWindow.document.write($(".content").html());
    myWindow.document.close();

}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/erv3ebj1/)

Comment: you MUST end with a  `myWindow.document.close();`

Comment: Thank you.. But it is not taking the style applied in this. How do I get that done?